# How to avoid unnecessary calls of Api in case of Field validation in Yup with formik in React JS if same filed is not getting changed?

Tags: reactjs, input, formik, yup

```
      .email("Email is not valid")
      .required("Email is required")
      .test(
        "email",
        emailRes ? "" : "Email Already Taken",
        async function (value) {
          if (!this.parent.email) {
            return true;
          }
          if (!Yup.string().email().isValidSync(value)) {
            setEmail("");
            return true;
          }
          try {
            await findEmail(value);
            if (emailRes) {
              return true; // Email is taken, validation fails
            } else {
              return false; // Email is available, validation passes
            }
          } catch (error) {
            // Handle error if the API call fails
            console.error("Error checking email:", error);
            return true; // Skip the check on error
          }
        }
```

**In above code if i am changing another field still this email validation calling api**

```
<input
  className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Enter Email"
                                {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}
                              />
```

Its calling api acurately but i dont want to call extra API.